# Azure CLI 2.0 to alter "Testing in production" routing for web apps

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

Is it possible to alter the azure web app static routing for "Testing in Production" using Azure CLI 2.0

You can set this using the `-RoutingRules` parameter of `Set-AzureWebsite` however i cannot find a CLI 2.0 alternative.

Does an alternative exist?

[image]

Comment: For now, Azure CLI 2.0 does not support this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no way to do it with CLI, but there's an open wishlist ticket on github.

You can comment or vote for it here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/2067

Also see: https://github.com/lostintangent/node-azure/issues/10

Comment: Is powershell the only method for doing this currently?

Comment: For now, we can do this via Azure portal or Azure powershell.